# Retrieve only one row using left join based on foreign key

Tags: sql-server, database, left-join

I have 2 relationship tables in the database.

One is `Class`

```
create table Class(
    CourseId int,
    CourseName varchar(50),
    LecturerId int,
    Class1Time  varchar(50),
    Class2Time varchar(50),
    Class1Place varchar(50),
    Class2Place varchar(50)
);
```

and `Lecturer`

```
create table Lecturer(
    Id int,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    primary key(Id)
);
```

`LecturerId` from `Class` table is foreign key of `Id` from `Lecturer`.
All I want is to select the data(one row) from both table based on the foreign key `LecturerId` = `specefic value`

I've tried using left join like

```
select Class.CourseName, Class.CourseId, Class.Class1Time, Class.Class2Time, Class.Class1Place, Class.Class2Place, Lecturer.Id, Lecturer.FirstName, Lecturer.LastName
from Class 
left join Lecturer 
    on Lecturer.Id = (select Lecturer.Id from Lecturer where LecturerId = Class.LecturerId)
    where Class.LecturerId = someValue;
go
```

But it causes the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

For example in the `Lecturer` table I have a `Id = 2001`

So I want perform the above query that need to return the below result like

```
CourseName - CourseId - Class1Time - Class2Time - Class1Place - Class2Place - Lecturer Infor(based on the Id)
```

Just only one row.

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results (as formatted text not images). I highly recommend the use of table aliases. And your entire join can be simplified to `left join Lecturer on Lecturer.Id = Class.LecturerId`

Comment: While I have solved the issue for you, please in future actually provide a [mre] with real sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using table aliases, with **all** columns aliased.

```
select C.CourseName, C.CourseId, C.Class1Time, C.Class2Time, C.Class1Place, C.Class2Place, L.Id, L.FirstName, L.LastName
from Class C
left join Lecturer L on L.Id = C.LecturerId
where C.LecturerId = @Id;
```

The reason you get that error is because:

```
(select Lecturer.Id from Lecturer where LecturerId = Class.LecturerId)
```

Is actually the same as:

```
(select Lecturer.Id from Lecturer where Class.LecturerId = Class.LecturerId)
```

Because `Lecturer` doesn't have a column called `LecturerId`, and because you haven't table qualified the column, SQL Server realises it does exist in `Class` and therefore uses it.

And since `Class.LecturerId = Class.LecturerId` is true for all records in the 'Lecturer' table you get all its ids returned.

And of course there is actually no reason to perform a subquery anyway, because you already have the value you are using the subquery to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following please.

```
DECLARE @LecturerId INT = 1

SELECT C.CourseName, C.CourseId, C.Class1Time, C.Class2Time, C.Class1Place, C.Class2Place, L.Id, L.FirstName, L.LastName
FROM Class AS C 
INNER JOIN Lecturer AS L ON L.Id = C.LecturerId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT C.CourseId, C.LecturerId
    FROM Class AS C     
    WHERE C.LecturerId = @LecturerId
    GROUP BY C.CourseId, C.LecturerId
) AS G ON G.CourseId = C.CourseId AND G.LecturerId = C.LecturerId
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation about how it solves the OP's problem in addition to working code.